# Form submit using 'form_tag' and namespaces in Ruby on Rails-3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3, submit

I am trying to call the 'update' method from 'ROOT_RAILS/controllers/users/account_controller.rb'

```
  ...
end

def update
  ...
end

def ...
```

using a "form_tag' in '/ROOT_RAILS/views/users/accounts/account.rb:

```
<% form_tag ( users_account_path, :method => :post ) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name %>
  <%= text_field_tag :surname %>
  <%= submit_tag_tag "Update" %>  
<% end %>
```

and having a namespace in 'ROOT_RAILS/config/routes.rb'

```
...
  namespace "users" do
    resources :accounts do
      collection do
        ...
      end
    end
  end
...
```

When I try to submit this form, I have a

```
No route matches "/users/accounts/2"
```

**What am I wrong?**

---

In 'form_tag' I tryed

```
:controller => "users/accounts", :action => "update"
```

instead of

```
users_account_path
```

that I think is the same.

---

If I use an ActiveRecord form works:

```
<%= form_for(@account, :url => { :action => "update", :controller => "accounts" } }) do |f| %>
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
users_accounts_path
```

Comment: 'users_accounts_path', in my case, seems to match the 'create' action.

Comment: I figured that's where you wanted to go, since you're using the post method? You probably know that, but "rake routes" will show you all available routes for your app.